# If option value is null the hide select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

actually i  get value dynamically.
when option value is null it will hide select tag> if option value is available the show select tag.

```
<select id="userList">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose one</option>
        <?php
            foreach($_SESSION ["userList"] as $key => $value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php

        } ?>
    </select>
----------
if ($("#userList").val() == NULL) {
  $('#userList').hide();
} else {
  $('#userList').show();
}
```

when option value is null it will hide select tag> if option value is available the show select tag.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?  Such as `NULL is not defined`.  Try `null`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it showing...

Comment: When you add option for the first time using php you can check if `$_SESSION ["userList"]` is null then hide that option else show .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give this a try :

```js
var optionsNull = $("#userList").find("option[value='']");

if (optionsNull) {
  optionsNull.hide();
}
```

Comment: @VickyNehare can you please check DOM and tell me what is the value of `value` attribute of the rendered input. You can check with developer tools.